# Fetch API cannot load, cors

Tags: reactjs, get, cors, fetch

In my `React` app I am trying to make a `GET` request from my heroku server to get a list of users:

```
https://blablabla.heroku.com/users
```

using the following request:

```
const sendSearch = fetch('/https://blablabla.heroku.com/users', {credentials: 'same-origin'})

function loadMyUsers(data) {
  data.json().then((jsonData) => {
    // console.log(jsonData)

  })
}

sendSearch.then(loadMyUsers)}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Fetch API cannot load https://blablabla.heroku.com/users.
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode
to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I tried changing my Fetch method to many things similar to:

```
const sendSearch = fetch('https://blablabla.heroku.com/users',{
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'mode': 'no-cors'
  }
})
```

but the problem persists.

How do I make the cross domain request?

Comment: You have to set the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers on your backend. The fetch request seems to work.

Comment: The problem is not with your front-end, as @Borma answered below, but with your server. You have to enable CORS on server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your heroku server you should add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to your response headers, or more specific `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080` if you wish.

On your production server though, you probably won't need this header, unless you have very good reason for cross origin requests.